# Problems with Windows XP Help and Support

Tags: windows-xp

I have a problem with the Help and Support application on Windows XP SP3.

Whenever I try to run it, Windows tells me that the file does not exist and when I did a search Windows did not find the EXE. When I had a look in services, there is no Help and Support service.

I tried "sfc /SCANNOW", but to no avail.
I also tried System Restore in the hope that SOMETHING might happen, but again, to no avail.

How can I restore the Help and Support app and service?

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/rebuildhelp.htm) should help, intitulated "Reinstalling Help and Support Center in Windows XP"

Comment: I tried that and the Help and Support Centre EXE is installed and the service was registered, however, when I try to start the service, I get the following error message:

Could not start the Help and Support Service on Local Computer.
Error 1083: The executable program that this service is confirgured to run in does not implement the service.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a [program](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/helpsvcfix.htm) which fixes the service problem.